# Emitting data from parent to child in vue not working

Tags: vue.js

There are many questions with this same issue, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am trying to send an event from my parent to my child. I know how the workflow is supposed to look like.

```
Read only life cycle: Parent > Prop > Child

Read/Update life cycle: Parent > Prop > Child > Emit > Parent > Update > Child Updates
```

I am using a prop, but there is nothing happening.

In the parent component:

```
         <v-row :class="'mb-3'" no-gutters >
            <v-col v-for="n in urlCount" :key='n'>
                <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile >
                    <team-url :editField="update"></team-url>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
```

---

```
update(): string {
    return 'enableEdit';
}
```

---

In the child component:

```
editField = '';

showField(url: string): string {
    return (this.url[url] == '' || this.editField == url)
}
```

I am trying to set the `editField` variable to `enableEdit` or send an event to trigger a method but I have not been able to successfully do it.

Comment: You aren’t emitting anything from the child component in the code you’ve shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parent wouldn't be sending events *down* to a child. Instead, the parent binds data to a child prop, and the child emits events (including any data) up to its parent. *Props down, events up.*

In your code, it looks like the parent component is binding the `update` computed prop to the `editField` prop of the `team-url` child component. The expected behavior in your question is a bit unclear, but I'll explain possible scenarios.

If you want `team-url` to react to changes in `editField` from the parent (e.g., to run a method), use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch):

```js
// TeamUrl.vue
export default {
  props: ['editField'],
  watch: {
    editField(newValue) {
      this.onEditFieldChange(newValue)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onEditFieldChange(newValue) {
      console.log(newValue)
    }
  },
}
```

If you want `team-url` to communicate data with its parent, the parent would first setup an [event listener](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) with [`v-on:EVENT_NAME="METHOD_NAME"`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) (or `@EVENT_NAME="METHOD_NAME"` shorthand):

```html
// Parent.vue
<template>
  <team-url @my-event="onMyEvent" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onMyEvent(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

And `team-url` could then send an event to its parent with [`vm.$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit):

```js
// TeamUrl.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    emitEventToParent(myData) {
      this.$emit('my-event', myData)
    }
  }
}
```